# How to insert node into ion-list based in alphabetic order

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, ionic4

I have a ion-list of items sorted in alphabetical order. I want to insert Alphabetical headings into the list (So 'A' heading at the start of a, 'B' at start of b etc), I want to do this by manipulating the dom by using some javascript in the .ts file after the page has loaded, but I can't fathom how (I'm a noob self teaching myself here!).

I've read loads of different approaches but nothing seemed to jumped out at me as the right solution. I've read about DomController which seemed great, seen a load of other alternatives too, just nothing that will let me read the string in alphabetical order and then insert a node.

This is the html before its compiled...

```
<div *ngIf="items.length > 0" class="list-mini">
  <ion-list lines="none">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" [routerLink]="['/details', item.payload.doc.id]">
      <ion-label>{{item.payload.doc.data
      ().recipeName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-thumbnail slot="end">
        <img [src]="item.payload.doc.data().image">
      </ion-thumbnail>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

This is it compiled (if that's needed)...

```
<ion-item _ngcontent-c1="" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/details,Jr24YUyo2IcjK2mA1DpY" class="in-list item ion-activatable ion-focusable item-label hydrated">
<ion-label _ngcontent-c1="" class="sc-ion-label-md-h sc-ion-label-md-s hydrated">Alias test name</ion-label>
<ion-thumbnail _ngcontent-c1="" slot="end" class="hydrated"><img _ngcontent-c1="" src="./assets/imgs/default_image.jpg"></ion-thumbnail>
</ion-item>
```

I'm pulling in data from firebase and I imagine the right way to do this would be to do something with data before I loop through it in the list, but thought manipulating the dom would be easier and I'd take the performance hit.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried using the index of the current ion-item using the syntax *ngFor=“let item of items; let i=index;”

Comment: @LloydNicholson no I haven’t. How would I insert something at the correct point using it? Sorry new to this stuff